# How can you get parent groups of joints in maya python

Tags: python, parent, maya

I have a hierarchy like this:

```
root_ctrl
 group2
   group3
     joint
```

I want to get names of the groups.

The output should be `['group2', 'group3']`.
i have tried using

```
parents = cmds.listRelatives('joint', allParents = True )
output = []
parents = (cmds.ls('joint', long=True)[0].split('|')[1:-1])
print parents
```

but this returns [joint,group3,group2,root_ctrl]. 
but i want [group3, group2] as the output.

Comment: Please post your attemps here. I'll suggest to read [mcve]

Comment: Like this? `cmds.ls("group*")` Vague questions get vague answers.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience caused to both of you. thanks for answering. i described the question in detail now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution if I understand your problem. This is a not very beautiful solution but it is still working.

```
hierarchy = cmds.ls('joint', long=True)[0]

def get_groups(hierarchy=None):
    nodes = [node for node in hierarchy.split('|') if node]
    return [x for x in nodes if cmds.listRelatives(x, shapes=True) is None and cmds.nodeType(x) == 'transform']

print(get_groups(hierarchy))
```

Comment: hi sgtlau , thanks for replying! this is giving me a error " TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' "

Comment: HI! I edited the code above, It should working now ;)
Groups are a transform type. So a group is a transform that has no shape as child.

Comment: thanks a million sgtlau it worked wonders thats exactly what i was looking for! a very happy new year 2020 to you :)